# SDL Image display slower then wanted

Tags: c, window, sdl-2

I want to use SDL2 to display a list of rgb values I have in memory to the screen. But my issue is that to update the screen for even a modestly sized image it takes a long time to preform.
On my laptop the example code takes 11.8 milliseconds to update the screen. Which would mean if you wanted a 60fps output it would only leave 4.2 milliseconds to do everything else.
Don't know what other method to use to display a image.

---

```
//gcc -Ofast -g "%f" `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2` -o SDL_test_3
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

//====---The_General_Use_Variables---====
unsigned char uc1;

long l1;

float f1;
float f2;
float f3;
float t1;
float t2;




int main(){
    int sx=1000;
    int sy=700;
    int did_work;
    
    //initilizes SDL
    did_work=SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    if (did_work!=0){printf("Issue_in_SDL_Init\n");}

    //Creates a window
    SDL_Window *window=NULL;
    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "win1", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, sx, sy, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

    //for a window to be on screen you need to be constantly monitering for window events
    SDL_Event windowEvent;
    if (!window){printf("SDL_CreateWindow_failed\n");}

    //assigned the window a surface
    SDL_Surface *screenSurface;
    screenSurface=SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    //creates a im_buffer
    unsigned char *im_buffer;im_buffer=malloc(sx*sy*3*sizeof(unsigned char));
    for(l1=0;l1<sx*sy*3;l1++){im_buffer[l1]=0;}

    //creates a screensurface with the im_buffer painted on it
    SDL_Surface *im_surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom((void*)im_buffer,
            sx,
            sy,
            24,          // bits per pixel = 24
            sx*3,  // pitch
            0x0000FF,              // red mask
            0x00FF00,              // green mask
            0xFF0000,              // blue mask
            0);

    
    //this command copys the im_buffer's window surface to the displayed window surface
    SDL_BlitSurface(im_surface, NULL, screenSurface, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    
    //setting up for loop
    int seconds=5;
    t1=clock();
    t1+=CLOCKS_PER_SEC*seconds;
    t2=clock();
    long counter=0;
    
    uc1=0;
    while(t2<t1){
        uc1++;
        counter++;
        SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent);
        
        for(l1=0;l1<sx*sy*3;l1+=3){im_buffer[l1]=uc1;}
        im_surface=SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom((void*)im_buffer,
            sx,
            sy,
            24,          // bits per pixel = 24
            sx*3,  // pitch
            0x0000FF,              // red mask
            0x00FF00,              // green mask
            0xFF0000,              // blue mask
            0);
        
        SDL_BlitSurface(im_surface, NULL, screenSurface, NULL);
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
        
        t2=clock();
        }
    f1=counter;
    f2=seconds;
    printf("average_fps=%f \n",f1/f2);
    printf("frametime=%f \n",1000*f2/f1);
}
```

---

Comment: The function [`clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock) will give you CPU time used by your program, not the actual time your program has been running. Since SDL probably uses multiple threads, the CPU time may be significantly higher than the actual time. Note that [SDL has its own timers](http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryTimer). You may be looking for [SDL_GetPerformanceCounter](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetPerformanceCounter).

Comment: Is it possible that `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);` is waiting for the next frame to start?

Comment: You are creating hundreds of large surfaces, but you are never releasing any of them. I suggest that you call [`SDL_FreeSurface`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_FreeSurface) when you no longer need the surface. This may improve performance.

Comment: You might go much faster with functions that use `SDL_Render` structs (e.g. `SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer` et. al.)

Comment: Assuming that [SDL_MUSTLOCK](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MUSTLOCK) returns zero (which it does with me when I run your code), you can modify the pixel data of an existing surface freely. There is no need to create a new surface every time you modify the data.

Comment: @CraigEstey: If the bitmap changes in every frame, so that a new `SDL_Texture` must be created for every frame, I doubt that it is possible to make it faster using an `SDL_Renderer`. According to my tests, the frame rate dropped by 30% by rewriting the program to use an `SDL_Renderer` and an `SDL_Texture`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Fair enough. I think your first comment re. `clock` is the root issue. I believe the timing calculations are incorrect. When I use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...)` in a function to get a floating point fractional seconds. Then, grab `t1` before and `t2` after the loop, change the loop to (e.g.) `for (counter = 0;  counter < 1000; ++counter)` and do `printf("fps=%f\n",counter / (t2 - t1));` I get an FPS of 328 and 3.1 ms / frame When I comment out the inner loop that changes `im_buffer`, the FPS goes to 396

Comment: Since you call `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom` before the loop, it is _not_ needed inside the loop. The latter just slows things down and creates memory leaks

Comment: @CraigEstey: My tests on Microsoft Windows have shown that it actually was not a problem to use the function `clock`. Even so, using that function does not seem like a good idea, in this case.

Comment: @CraigEstey: You were right that better performance can be achieved by using an `SDL_Texture` and `SDL_Renderer`. I was able to increase the performance compared to OP's code, by using "streaming" textures. See my answer for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most games put their textures into video memory so that the [GPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_processing_unit) can handle all of the rendering. This will normally give you the most performance, because that is what GPUs are optimized for.

However, in your code, you are updating the surface/texture once per frame. This is bad for performance. Instead of doing this, it is generally better not to modify the textures, or if you do need such visual effects, this should generally be done inside video memory with the GPU, for example by using [shaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader). The CPU is generally much slower.

In SDL 2.0, an [`SDL_Surface`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Surface) is a [sprite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(computer_graphics)) in system memory, which is used by the CPU. If you want to move the sprite to video memory, where it is generally faster and handled by the GPU, you must convert the `SDL_Surface` to an [`SDL_Texture`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Texture), for example using the function [`CreateTextureFromSurface`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface).

However, when I converted your code to use an `SDL_Texture` and `CreateTextureFromSurface` and tested it on Microsoft Windows, I did not get a performance increase. Instead, the frame rate dropped by about 30% compared to your original code. This is because I was calling `CreateTextureFromSurface` once per frame, because the texture was changing in every frame.

After that, I tried creating a streaming texture, which is an `SDL_Texture` created with [`SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_TextureAccess). This allows you to use the function [`LockTexture`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture), which modifies the texture in an efficient manner. By doing this, I was able to improve the frame rate by 46% compared to your original code. Here is my modified code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_render.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//these variables were taken from OP's code, but the
//data type of some of these variables was changed
unsigned char uc1;
double f1;
double f2;
Uint64 t1;
Uint64 t2;


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    //timer values used for benchmarking
    Uint64 TimeStart, TimeLockTexture = 0, TimeRendering = 0;

    //define dimensions of window
    int sx=1000;
    int sy=700;

    //initilize SDL
    if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0 )
    {
        printf("SDL_Init failed!\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //create a window and renderer
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    if ( SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer( sx, sy, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN, &window, &renderer ) != 0 )
    {
        printf("SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer failed!\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //create streaming texture
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTexture( renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB24, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, sx, sy );
    if ( texture == NULL )
    {
        printf( "CreateTexture failed!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //these lines were taken over from OP's code, but I
    //replaced the function call "clock" with SDL timer
    //functions
    Uint64 seconds = 5;
    t1=SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
    t1+=SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency()*seconds;
    t2=SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
    long counter=0;

    //these lines were taken over from OP's code
    uc1=0;
    while(t2<t1)
    {
        //these lines were taken over from OP's code
        SDL_Event windowEvent;
        uc1++;
        counter++;
        SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent);

        //start measuring the time
        TimeStart = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

        //lock the texture
        unsigned char *pixels;
        int pitch;
        if ( SDL_LockTexture( texture, NULL, (void**)&pixels, &pitch ) != 0 )
        {
            printf( "LockTexture failed!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //make modifications to texture
        for ( int i = 0; i < sy; i++)
        {
            unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)pixels + i * pitch;
            unsigned char *limit = p + sx * 3;

            while( p < limit )
            {
                *p++ = uc1; //red value
                *p++ = 0;   //green value
                *p++ = 0;   //blue value
            }
        }

        //unlock the texture, which updates the texture in
        //video memory from system memory
        SDL_UnlockTexture( texture );

        //remember the amount of time required for working
        //on the locked texture
        TimeLockTexture += SDL_GetPerformanceCounter() - TimeStart;

        //start measuring the time
        TimeStart = SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();

        //do the rendering
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, texture, NULL, NULL );
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        //remember the amount of time required for rendering
        TimeRendering += SDL_GetPerformanceCounter() - TimeStart;

        //this line was taken over from OP's code
        t2=SDL_GetPerformanceCounter();
    }

    //cleanup
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    //print benchmarking results
    f1=(double)counter;
    f2=(double)seconds;
    printf("average_fps=%f \n",f1/f2);
    printf("frametime=%f \n",1000*f2/f1);
    printf("seconds spent writing to locked texture:  %f\n", (double)TimeLockTexture / SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency() );
    printf("seconds spent doing the actual rendering: %f\n", (double)TimeRendering / SDL_GetPerformanceFrequency() );

    //cleanup
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

On my 7 year old Desktop-GPU, this program has the following output:

```
average_fps=475.400000
frametime=2.103492
seconds spent writing to locked texture:  3.708509
seconds spent doing the actual rendering: 1.284001
```

However, even using the method described above, it is still quite bad for performance to change the texture in every frame. If I remove the code which changes the texture in every frame, the frame rate increases by about 1200% (i.e. by a factor of 12).

I get a similar performance increase if I reduce the size of the texture to 32*32 pixels and use that texture for filling the entire screen, by stretching the texture. This clearly shows that the bottleneck is updating the (large) texture.

In your question, you wrote:

> Which would mean if you wanted a 60fps output it would only leave 4.2 milliseconds to do everything else.

This statement is inaccurate, unless your laptop only has a single CPU core. If you have more than one CPU core, then you can make one CPU core handle the creation of the individual pixels and sending them to the graphics card using SDL, while the other CPU core handles everything else in your program that it not directly related to SDL. This can be done by using [multithreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)).

It would probably also be possible to use two threads (i.e. two CPU cores) for modifying the texture. However, I doubt that this would be worth the cost of [synchronizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)#Thread_or_process_synchronization) the threads. Since you are already achieving the desired frame rate of 60 FPS when using a single thread for modifying every single pixel on the screen and passing them to SDL, it would probably be best to make this thread do this and nothing else, and let another thread do all the other work.

Note that certain SDL functions should only be called by one thread. For example, according to [this page from the official libsdl documentation](http://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryRender), you should not be calling functions from `SDL_render.h` from different threads.

Comment: Just came back to this and I am flabbergasted at how nice the responses have been. Though I am still not sure where to go. I tried freeing the surface on every loop but the difference in performance was within random error. Looking at the texture and renderer method proposed by Andreas, on my laptop his code produces a frametime similar to my method of 11 milliseconds but with some odd results. On my laptop the time spent writing locked texture is 4.89 seconds while time spent doing actual rendering is 0.065 seconds. Odd. Should have said this is on a Lifebook AH512 running Ubuntu.

Comment: Sadly there is a character limit. Did a quick experiment with Andrea's code and found the odd result that 9 of those 11 milliseconds is just on the locking and unlocking of the texture.

Comment: @Robin: Freeing the `SDL_Surface` on every loop also did not have any noticable performance impact with me. However, it is still important to do this, because otherwise you have a [resource leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_leak), which may cause a noticable impact in different situations.

Comment: @Robin: The function [`SDL_UnlockTexture`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UnlockTexture) does more than just unlocking the texture. It updates the texture in video memory from the system memory that was previously locked.

Comment: @Robin: The Lifebook AH512 seems to use a [Intel HD Graphics 3000 chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Graphics_Technology#Gen6_Architecture). As far as I can tell, this is a simple graphics chip that does not have its own video memory, so it must use system memory as video memory. This explains why moving the sprite to video memory (by using an `SDL_Texture` instead of an `SDL_Surface`) does not give you any performance improvement, because both are the same in your case.

Comment: Sorry if this comes off as naive but if moving the texture to the gpu is the bottleneck here does that mean that there isn't much that can be done under SDL to improve the performance.

Comment: @Robin: However, as far as I can tell, the main problem is that you are modifying a very large texture in every frame by reloading it from system memory. Even a modern discrete graphics card with a powerful GPU would not like that. Since all pixels are identical in your code, you could improve performance significantly by creating a very small texture and then rendering that very small texture to the entire screen, so that the small texture is resized to fill the entire screen. By reducing the size of the texture to 32*32 pixels, I improved performance by a factor of 12.

Comment: @Robin: As stated in my answer, you should generally modify textures using [shaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader) if you want them to change in every frame, so that all of the modification takes place inside the GPU using video memory, and not inside the CPU using system memory. Anything else is a performance killer (unless you are only changing small textures). However, I am not sure if this also applies to graphics chips that do not have any video memory.

Comment: @Robin: If you want to have full control of every single pixel on the screen using system memory, then I'm afraid that there are not many possibilities of optimizing your code.

Comment: @Robin: Please note that meanwhile, I have added several paragraphs to the bottom of my answer regarding using multiple CPU cores, which may be helpful to you. If I am not mistaken, your Lifebook AH512 has two CPU cores.

Comment: I think you need to run both programs on the same system to get an apples-to-apples comparison. I've run your version and a "cleaned up" version of the original code. On my system, I get an FPS of: `orig=325.417392 ce1=323.589809 aw1=268.198135 ce2=395.773949 aw2=639.179152` The `*2` are _without_ [CPU] drawing to the surface. AFAICT, the "drawing" methods aren't equivalent, so the real test is just the rendering `*2` versions.

Comment: Good point on the use of multiple cores, that is something I really need to look into, so I guess tomorrow will be applying the sieve of Eratosthenes to multiple cores to learn about how to do it. Thank you, your help has been going above and beyond all my expectations.